# Open Explorer and Highlight Specific File with PowerShell

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, powershell

There are programs allows us to "View File in Explorer" on a file it opened or is listing (e.g. iTunes). Upon selecting that function, the file explorer is opened to the path containing that file and the corresponding file is highlighted. This is the feature I would like to emulate with PowerShell.

It is simple to open to a directory with PowerShell (i.e. `explorer $path`). However, attempting to include a file just opens that file with the associated program (e.g. doing `explorer $path/$file` where `$file` is a `.txt` file will just open `$file` in `notepad` or whatever program is defined to handle `.txt` files).

**Can PowerShell open the File Explorer to a specific path AND highlight a specific file?**

Comment: Answered here  http://stackoverflow.com/a/12162855/2186591

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to select a specific file by sending the `select` command to `explorer.exe`. This is actually native to `cmd`. So, the `$path` is restricted to the traditional DOS format (e.g. using `\` only instead of both `\` and `/`).

```
# Both Works on PowerShell 5
explorer /select,$path
Invoke-Expression "explorer '/select,$path'"
```

This info is from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/320509/is-it-possible-to-open-an-explorer-window-from-powershell/12162855#12162855) by [Alex](https://stackoverflow.com/users/26564/alex) (thanks to [AEonAX](https://superuser.com/users/297002/aeonax) for pointing this out).

Comment: Also works with double quotes `explorer.exe "/select,C:\path\to\file.txt"`. I've found that the important thing is to wrap the whole /select and file name in quotes.